# If statement to copy and paste "Lunch Breaks" over duration of 00:40:00

Tags: excel, vba

Duration time is throwing me for a loop.

I tried changing duration formatting to decimal but it made it ugly.

```vb
Sub Long_Lunch()

lastrow = Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Lunch Break" Then
        If Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(i, 6).Value > "00:40:00" Then
            Worksheets("Raw Data").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("D").Activate
            b = Worksheets("D").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("D").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("Raw Data").Activate
Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(1, 1).Select
MsgBox ("Done")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Times (and dates) are stored as numbers on the spreadsheet - `00:40:00` would be 0.277777 (40/1440) on the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

- Destination worksheet is not necessary to be activated for `Copy` a range.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Long_Lunch()
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastRowD As Long
    Dim i As Long, Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = Worksheets("D")
    With Worksheets("Raw Data")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, 4).Value = "Lunch Break" Then
                If Format(.Cells(i, 6).Value, "hh:mm:ss") > "00:40:00" Then
                    lastRowD = Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Rows(i).Copy Sht.Cells(lastRowD + 1, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm and much quicker.  Is that because desination worksheet not activated? I am just starting with vba so definitely have a lot to learn

Comment: @JesseCantrell It's worth to read  
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)